# сохранить Imagefile в модели Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, файлы

Есть моедель

```
class ImageModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    avatar = models.ImageField('Аватар', upload_to='avatars')
```

Как загрузить файл в модель не из обьета request(request.FILES).
Я получаю файл

```
import requests
img_file = requests.get(img_url)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile

img = ImageModel()
img.avatar.save(some_file_name, ContentFile(img_file.content))
img.save()
```

Comment: спасибо. сам дошел до такого. from django.core.files.images import ImageFile;
im_file = ImageFile(BytesIO(response.content));
info.flag.save('fl/img.bmp', im_file, save=True);